# Remove certain columns from sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a master sheet, but out of this sheet I only need certain columns to be displayed. Doing it manually is taking a long time and this worksheet is something I have to do once in a fortnight.

Can anyone please suggest VBA code to do this?

Comment: why don't you just record the action, and see which code is generated? That should give you all you need.

Comment: what code do you have ? This is a site for programming not doing your homework or work.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you need to delete columns numbers 13, 58 and 101, then do as follows:

```
Sub DeleteColumns()
    Columns(101).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(58).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(13).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

For keeping the original column numbers, make sure you delete them from the highest to the lowest. Note that columns are numbered from 1 (which is "A") onwards.

If you don't want to delete the columns, but just hide them, then use the `Hidden` property:

```
Sub HideColumns()
    Columns(13).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ' ... etc.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go as follows:

```
Sub ColumnsDelete()
   Range("A1, E1, AH1").EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

Sub ColumnsHide()
   Range("A1, E1, AH1").EntireColumn.Hidden=True
End Sub
```

Where you simply have to type columns headers followed by any row number (I chose "1" for simplicity)